# sort_buffer_size vs innodb_sort_buffer_size

Tags: mysql

Mysql version <5.6 shows variable 'sort_buffer_size' and 'myisam_sort_buffer_size'.
However when upgraded to mysql 5.6, it now shows ' innodb_sort_buffer_size' in addition to both previous.

SO what actualy is the difference between sort_buffer_size vs innodb_sort_buffer_size. it is replacement or new different variable.

If this is duplicate question, please do point me to satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As written in documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_sort_buffer_size) ,

`innodb_sort_buffer_size` specifies the size of sort buffers used for sorting data during creation of an InnoDB index.

While `sort_buffer_size` is just a per-connection variable and do not belongs to any specific storage engine.

Answer (score 4):

More info about `sort_buffer_size`:

“On Linux, there are thresholds of 256KB and 2MB where larger values may significantly slow down memory allocation”--from documentation

This is because, when the value is over the threshold, software use mmap() which is slow instead of malloc() to alloc new mem.

Here is a test case:

```
mysqlslap -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -q ' SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM sbtest ORDER BY pad LIMIT 1' -c 100 --create-schema=test -i 10
```

**Results**:
`sort_buffer_size`  : Average number of seconds to run all queries
250K                : 1.318s
512K                : 1.944s
3M                  : 2.412s

[reference(in Chinese)](https://www.cnblogs.com/wajika/p/6718552.html)

And `sort_buffer_size` works only for sort operations such as `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` no matter which storage engine you are using. While `innodb_sort_buffer_size` **ONLY** works when adding index to a innodb table. The innodb sort buffer is released just after adding index.